# Passing paremeters into Functions when using EXEC command

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to learn SQL on SQL Server and several functions/SPs require parameters. For example, when I enter "exec sys.fn", the intellisense brings up various functions/SPs and some have brackets which describe parameters.

How do I pass the parameter in? Although I saw some examples, they were for custom SPs so I couldn't quite apply them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EXECUTE yoursp @parametername1 = value1, @parametername2 = value2
```

and so on. If you supply all necessary parameters for the SP, you can also just state them in order, for example:

```
EXECUTE yoursp value1, value2
```